# Typescript equivalent of elvis “?: return” operator

Tags: typescript, null

The following code in Kotlin return out of the parent function if the result of nextbitmap() is null

```
 val bitmap = nextbitmap() ?: return
 // something the relies on bitmap not being null
```

What is the Typescript equivalent of such operator ?

Comment: The `?: return` (or throw) form is specific, being distinct from a coalescing from, which does not otherwise affect flow control. Unlike Kotlin, `return` keyword in TypeScript is distinctly not an expression. Hopefully the title edit with elicit answers reflecting the intent-as-shown.

Comment: What do you mean by "*out of the parent function*"? JavaScript can only return from the current function.

Comment: By "parent" I meant the function that calls the snippet above. or "current" as you mean

Answer (score 2):

There is no such operator, and `return` can never be part of an expression. In TypeScript, you'll have to use a separate `if` statement for this:

```
const bitmap = nextbitmap();
if (!bitmap) return;
// something the relies on bitmap not being null
```

(or use `bitmap != null` in the condition, if `bitmap` has a primitive type)